# Fermion Fermion Spin-l CFT correlator in 3D in position space (not embedding space)?

Tags: resource-recommendations, conformal-field-theory, fermions, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I am looking for a reference for $\langle \psi(x_1) \psi(x_2) \mathcal{O}^{\mu_1 \mu_2 \dots \mu_{l}}(x_3) \rangle$ and $\langle \psi(x_1) \phi(x_2) \mathcal{\psi}^{\mu_1 \mu_2 \dots \mu_{l}}(x_3) \rangle$ correlator in position space. 
Here $\mathcal{\psi}^{\mu_1 \dots \mu_l}$ is a fermionic primary operator with spin (l+1/2).

Most of the literature is in embedding space, but I was wondering if the somewhere it has been given in position space.

Comment: Do you need it in some specific configuration, or you want a general formula?

Comment: In any case, what is the problem with taking the embedding space expression and converting it to position space?

Comment: Okay, I'll try that, I was a bit confused how is $I_{\mu \nu}$ expressed in terms of pauli matrices. But I found the expression which does that.

Comment: @Peter Kravchuk : By the way a generalization to arbitrary dimensions of it has been done in a paper by Hiroshi Isono, which seems very interesting, do have a look.

Comment: If you are referring to arXiv:1706.02835, I had a look at that paper. While their treatment of embedding formalism spinors may be correct (I haven't looked carefully into that), part of their treatment of conformal blocks appeared definitely wrong to me. Namely their claim that they can write fermionic exchange as a derivative of scalar block appears too naive. There is a way of doing that, which we found in arXiv:1706.07813, but it is more complicated than what their paper seems to suggest.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. But I was trying to go from embedding space to real space, but somehow I am stuck. I am getting a bit confused while taking derivatives, because when I try to compute $\langle S_1 S_2 \rangle $ I am getting $(s_2. \cancel{x_1}.s_1 - s_1.\cancel{y}.s_2)$, which jumbles the indices, can you help me in computing them ?

Comment: sorry I've been away for a while. I am not sure what is the source of your confusion (if you still have it). Did you have a look at the embedding formalism setup in 1511.01497 or 1508.00012?

Comment: Hi peter, sorry for such a delay in replying. I have looked at the setup of the formalism. I have understood how to proceed, thanks!